# pygame error, No video mode has been set

Tags: python, pygame

I am just setting up some functions for my game but my script fails to load the image

```
#used variables
# x, y for alien location
# nPc for the aliens image
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#



#set up
import pygame, sys, random, time, math
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()


nPc = '/home/claude/Dropbox/Bowtie/Prisim/Images/Alien_Races/Standered/alien_1.png'


nPc = pygame.image.load(nPc).convert_alpha()

def loc_alien():
        x = random.randint(0, 400)
        y = randaom.randint(0, 400)


def spawn_alien(x, y):
        screen.blit(nPc, (x, y))
```

when I run this I wont nothing to happen as I am not using the functions yet, but when I do run it I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/claude/Dropbox/Bowtie/Prisim/Scripts/aliens.py", line 26, in <module>
    nPc = pygame.image.load(nPc).convert_alpha()
error: No video mode has been set
```

anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You might find this helpful: http://inventwithpython.com/pygamecheatsheet.png

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe that you need to call:

```
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600)) # change to the real resolution
```

this call will actually return the surface that you want to blit on. Below is the documentation from the linked resource.

> **[pygame.display.set_mode()](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_mode)**
>
> *Initialize a window or screen for display*
>
> ```
> set_mode(resolution=(0,0), flags=0, depth=0) -> Surface
> ```
>
> This function will create a display Surface. The arguments passed in
>   are requests for a display type. The actual created display will be
>   the best possible match supported by the system.
>
> The resolution argument is a pair of numbers representing the width
>   and height. The flags argument is a collection of additional options.
>   The depth argument represents the number of bits to use for color.
>
> The Surface that gets returned can be drawn to like a regular Surface
>   but changes will eventually be seen on the monitor.
>
> If no resolution is passed or is set to (0, 0) and pygame uses SDL
>   version 1.2.10 or above, the created Surface will have the same size
>   as the current screen resolution. If only the width or height are set
>   to 0, the Surface will have the same width or height as the screen
>   resolution. Using a SDL version prior to 1.2.10 will raise an
>   exception.
>
> It is usually best to not pass the depth argument. It will default to
>   the best and fastest color depth for the system. If your game requires
>   a specific color format you can control the depth with this argument.
>   Pygame will emulate an unavailable color depth which can be slow.
>
> When requesting fullscreen display modes, sometimes an exact match for
>   the requested resolution cannot be made. In these situations pygame
>   will select the closest compatible match. The returned surface will
>   still always match the requested resolution.
>
> The flags argument controls which type of display you want. There are
>   several to choose from, and you can even combine multiple types using
>   the bitwise or operator, (the pipe “|” character). If you pass 0 or no
>   flags argument it will default to a software driven window. Here are
>   the display flags you will want to choose from:
>
> ```
> pygame.FULLSCREEN    create a fullscreen display
> pygame.DOUBLEBUF     recommended for HWSURFACE or OPENGL
> pygame.HWSURFACE     hardware accelerated, only in FULLSCREEN
> pygame.OPENGL        create an OpenGL renderable display
> pygame.RESIZABLE     display window should be sizeable
> pygame.NOFRAME       display window will have no border or controls
> ```
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> # Open a window on the screen
> screen_width=700
> screen_height=400
> screen=pygame.display.set_mode([screen_width,screen_height])
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Do not forgot to create your surface before creating variables with images in it

like this:

```py
win = pygame.display.set_mode((576, 1024))
background_day = pygame.image.load("background-day.png").convert()
```

not like this:

```py
background_day = pygame.image.load("background-day.png").convert()
win = pygame.display.set_mode((576, 1024))
```