# pygame error: No video mode has been set w/livewires

Tags: python, pygame

In my pygame file I have:

```
from livewires import games
import math, random

class Ship(games.Sprite):
    image = games.load_image("images\ship.bmp", transparent = True)
```

and it gives the error:

```
pygame error: No video mode has been set
```

I am using livewires to import pygame with, and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18905989/pygame-error-no-video-mode-has-been-set) did not give a correct answer for my computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize your `livewires` display like so:

```
from livewires import games
import math, random

games.init(screen_width = 640, screen_height = 480, fps = 60)

# game logic here

games.screen.mainloop() # mainloop of the display
```

Comment: The program does not display an error, but the window instead flashes and goes away after a half second

Comment: Did you call the mainloop of the display?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with livewires, I use the underlying game engine Pygame that it is based on. I suggest you do the same, but if you want to stick with livewires, try reading Python Programming for the Absolute Beginner by Michael Dawson. Funny guy, great read, interesting examples.

Comment: I'm actually learning from that book now. I was doing the sample program in chapter 12

Answer (score 0):

Like that post says, you need to set

```
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600)) # change to the real resolution
```

Somewhere outside of your ship class (like your main method). Your ship class is used to produce objects in your game, not create the game window.

If you are keeping all your classes in one file, try something like:

```
from pygame.locals import *
from livewires import games
import math, random

def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600)) # change to the real resolution


class Ship(games.Sprite):
    image = games.load_image("images\ship.bmp", transparent = True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```