# Why do I get an AttributeError when calling a class in a seperate module?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame, attributeerror

I'm (attempting) to recreate Mario level 1-1 in Pygame with Python 2.7.12. these are the two relevant files:

main.py:
http://pastebin.com/HXmBdJ2a

mario.py:
http://pastebin.com/29xu1tMM
My problem is: when I run main.py, the interpreter gives me this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/path/to/main.py", line 6, in <module>
    import mario
  File "C:\path\to\mario.py", line 7, in <module>
    import main
  File "C:\path\to\main.py", line 47, in <module>
    game = Game()
  File "C:\path\to\main.py", line 26, in __init__
    self.main_loop()
  File "C:\path\to\main.py", line 39, in main_loop
    self.Mario = mario.Mario()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Mario'
Process finished with exit code 1
```

I'm confused, as mario.py does the class Mario. If I try to run mario.py, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/path/to/mario.py", line 7, in <module>
    import main
  File "C:\path\to\main.py", line 6, in <module>
    import mario
  File "C:\path\to\mario.py", line 12, in <module>
    sheet = pygame.image.load("../assets/images/MarioLuigiSprites.png").convert()
pygame.error: No video mode has been set
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Could anyone explain this to me?

EDIT: I fixed it by adding:
`import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "scripts")
import mario`

Comment: Try importing mario.Mario

Comment: And also, try doing this `screen = pygame.display.set_mode((num, num))` to avoid the No video mode error

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18905989/pygame-error-no-video-mode-has-been-set

Comment: I tried import mario.Mario, and got: ImportError: No module named Mario

Comment: The problem is that the Game class doesn't have an attribute called Mario, as you do not define it in the `__init__` of your Game class. Either you have             `self.Mario = mario.Mario()` in the `__init__` of Game class or call just             `Mario = mario.Mario()`. Plus, why do you call `mario = Mario()` at the end of your `mario.py`? You should try to remove that.

Comment: Could it be that since there are errors in Mario, that main won't even acknowledge the class?

Comment: @ragledwhy remove `mario = Mario()` in the mario.py at the end and just call `Mario = mario.Mario()` in main.py and not `self.Mario = mario.Mario()`.

Comment: Plus why do you need to `import main` in mario.py ? I think you can remove that.

Comment: You have a [circular import](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22187279/python-circular-importing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Mario'` in this case come from the fact that the `Game` class doesn't have an attribute called `Mario`, as you do not define it in the **init** of your Game class. To make it clear, you do not have:

```
class Game(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.fps = 60
        self.showfps = True
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()

        # Set FPS
        self.clock.tick(self.fps)

        self.Mario = mario.Mario()  # notice this line!!!
        .......
        .......
```

Either you have `self.Mario = mario.Mario()` in the `__init__` of Game class or call just `Mario = mario.Mario()` in the code you have.
This means that keeping the code you have already you should do:

```
def main_loop(self):
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                self.closegame()
        Mario = mario.Mario()  # notice: it's not self.Mario....
        DISPLAYSURF.fill(const.BLACK)
```

Side note: why do you call `mario = Mario()` at the end of your mario.py?   Try to remove that.
And if you do not use any methods or classes defined in `main.py` you can remove `import main` in `mario.py`.

Comment: Thanks. Now when I run main I get a different error:                             sheet = pygame.image.load("../assets/images/MarioLuigiSprites.png").convert()
pygame.error: No video mode has been set

Comment: Did you check already one of the comment from @Nikhil Raghavendra on that video issue? Again here if you didn't look: http://inventwithpython.com/pygamecheatsheet.png and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18905989/pygame-error-no-video-mode-has-been-set

Comment: I still get the no video mode has been set error even when I don't use a tuple in pygame.display.set_mode(). I tried importing mario.Mario after I set the display, and get: ImportError: No module named Mario