# No Video Mode Has Been Set Error, cannot load in images

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to load in several png files for a pygame project, and return them as an array from a function. The problem is when I try to use my function, I get an error saying that the .convert_alpha() method cannot be performed because no video mode has been set.

Im not too familiar with pygame, so I dont even know if what I am doing is proper syntax, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

```py
def loadTextures():

    UpEarl = pygame.image.load("UpFacingEarl.png")
    LeftEarl=pygame.image.load("LeftFacingEarl.png")
    RightEarl=pygame.image.load("RightFacingEarl.png")
    DownEarl=pygame.image.load("DownFacingEarl.png")
    Texturelist=[UpEarl,LeftEarl,RightEarl,DownEarl]

    NewTextureList=[]
    for item in Texturelist:
        item = pygame.transform.scale(item, (65,64))
        item=item.convert_alpha()
        NewTextureList.append(item)

    return NewTextureList
```

Comment: Did you tried already [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18906030/10170240)?